# Excel 2013 Round Formula

Tags: excel, rounding, formula

I have an array that pulls pricing from another worksheet in the same workbook depending on quantities of items sold.  My boss created the array to use something that pulls up the row and then this formula uses that reference to get the pricing from that row.  He said it doesn't impact the file size like vlookup does.  The question is, how can I have excel return the value and round it to whole pennies?  For example. 91.1765 should be rounded to 91.18.

Here's the formula I'm trying to add into:

```
=IF($B4="","",OFFSET('Product Lookup'!$J$1,'Pricing Worksheet'!$K4-1,M$3))
```

I'm not sure how to compound the functions in formulas like this, so any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: So what is your question

Comment: The question is, how can I have excel return the value and round it to whole pennies?  

=IF($B4="","",Round,2,(OFFSET('Product Lookup'!$J$1,'Pricing Worksheet'!$K4-1,M$3)) does not work.

Comment: How does `=IF($B4="","", ROUND(OFFSET('Product Lookup'!$J$1,'Pricing Worksheet'!$K4-1,M$3), 2))` work?

Comment: Thank you ZedFoxus, that works well as long as the value is numeric.  There are some cases where we are asking the individual using the form to contact us for pricing assistance and the instructions are not numeric.  Any idea how I can round it when it's a number and not return a "#value" error when it's not?